# Reddit automod regex

Tags: regex, yaml, reddit

I am trying to configure my automoderator for reddit. I have this regex:

```
title (regex): ['(BUYING|SELLING):.*\|{1}.*', '[META].*']
```

I put it into https://www.regex101.com/ and it says that it matches when I put in the string

```
SELLING: asdada | dsdda
```

But then on reddit it doesn't comment when it matches with the comment rule. Is this a regex problem or just a reddit problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try `title (regex): ["(BUYING|SELLING):[\\s\\S]*\\|[\\s\\S]*", "\\[META\\][\\s\\S]*"]`

Comment: What flavor regex are you using?  Your regex seems to attempt to match more than just your sample text.  Maybe you can provide a few variations for strings you are trying to match?

Comment: @jmargolisvt it's trying to match `(BUYING|SELLING):.*\|{1}.*` and `[META].*`. Is uses yaml regex.

Comment: @stribizhev that doesn't work, still not matching it

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the whole automoderator rule?